# Magento 1.9 virtual product checkout

Tags: magento, virtual, checkout, product

I'm having trouble checking out with a virtual product. The checkout works properly with simple products.

The error I get when i check the console is:

---

(index):620 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at beforeBillSave ((index):620)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):569)

---

The code is:

```
function beforeBillSave() {
        var selectedCity = false;
        var action = CITIES_ACTION;
        var selectCountry = $('billing:country_id').value;
        var stateId = $('billing:region_id').value;
        if (document.getElementById('billing:use_for_shipping_yes').checked) {
            getAjaxReqestShip(action, selectCountry, stateId, normalImputShip,selectedCity)
        } else {
            $('shipping:city').replace(normalImputShip);
        }

        billing.save()
    }
```

---

The problem seems to be that there are no radio buttons of 'Ship to this address' and 'ship to different address' present when checking out with a virtual product.

I tried to look for this code everywhere but failed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that there isn't element exists with the given ID. You can wrap this code in this IF condition.

```
if(document.getElementById('billing:use_for_shipping_yes').length){
// your IF condition code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that what you're saying will work, but where is the file with this code? Where should I change this?

Comment: What do you want to change ? you want to enable shipping for virtual products !!?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was pretty stupid of me to forget that I could just enable the template path hints and find the file which has the code.